Does a controlled mount's initiative revert when dismounted?
The general rule for Combat - Initiative is that:

Initiative remains the same from round to round.

However, a controlled mount's initiative changes to match its rider's:

The initiative of a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. It moves on your turn...

Meanwhile, an independent mount:

retains its place in the initiative order and moves and acts as it likes.

I haven't found anything in the rules that clarifies whether the mount's initiative reverts to its former "independent" initiative after a rider dismounts or if it simply retains its new initiative, which is generally fixed from round to round. Is there any rule or clarification in the new 2024 edition that addresses this situation?

It retains the new initiative.
Absent explicit rules to indicate that a controlled mount's initiative reverts to its former order, we must conclude that it retains its new initiative, according to the rules cited in the original question.
After dismounting, both rider and mount resolve their current, shared turn. And, in subsequent turns, the shared initiative qualifies as a tie. However, the RAW are only explicit about ties between characters or ties between monsters.

If a tie occurs, the DM decides the order among tied monsters, and the players decide the order among tied characters. The DM decides the order if the tie is between a monster and a player character.

There are no further clarifications to decide when the relevant tie is between a "monster" and a PC, so the decision comes down GM fiat. However, a good guideline may be whether or not the creature is friendly to the characters. If the creature is friendly, perhaps the characters should decide. Conversely, the GM should decide when the creature is unfriendly (though this is an edge-case with respect to controlled mounts).
